# Recuperar datos de url despues de base64_encode

Tags: php

Quiero dar otro aspecto a mis `url`, he pasado `base64_encode` a la parte de la url dónde están las variables.
Evidentemente, en el archivo de destino, no puedo usar `$_GET['***'];`.

¿Hay alguna forma de recuperar los datos?

Se me ocurre capturar la url, pasarla `base64_decode` y luego recuperar los datos, pero no consigo hacerlo

```html
$urlModify = "id=".$row['id']."&numero=".$row['numero']."&cliente=".$row['cliente'].........etc;
  $urlCode = base64_encode($urlModify);
  $urlCode = "https://*********?" . $urlCode;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En vez de codificar toda la url, he codificado sólo los valores de las variables de la siguiente forma

```html
  $urlModify = "https://*******?";
  $urlModify .= "id=".base64_encode($row['id']);
  $urlModify .= "&numero=".base64_encode($row['numero']);
  $urlModify .= "&cliente=".base64_encode($row['cliente']);
  $urlModify .= "&direccion=".base64_encode($row['direccion']);
  ..........etc
```

Y los he recuperado así

```html
    $idGet = base64_decode($_GET['id']);
    $averiaGet = base64_decode($_GET['averia']);
    $emailGet = base64_decode($_GET['email']);
    $clienteGet = base64_decode($_GET['cliente']);
```